# IIS URL rewrite to html not a subdirectory of the same name

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, jekyll

My jekyll-generated static website on IIS is directing to the subdirectory instead of an actual html file of the same name (both in root). How am I able to change the web.config so that  it will redirect/rewrite to the html?

I am deploying a jekyll-generated static website on IIS. I have searched the interweb and now the default .html extension name is not needed for URLs. I used the following code in the Web.Config to remove html extension:

```
<rule name="Redirect to clean URL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([a-z0-9/]+).html$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>

<rule name="RewriteHTML" enabled="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.html" />
</rule>
```

Here is my the example of my root:

```
-----
|---    
|---   
|          |---1.html
|---/sub---|---2.html
|          |---3.html
|
|---index.html
|
|---sub.html
|
|
|---noExtension.html
|
|
|
-----
```

and what I have achieved for now is like:

http://www.example.com/             =====> index.html

http://www.example.com/noextension  =====> noextension.html

http://www.example.com/sub          =====> /sub ** instad of sub.html **

http://www.example.com/sub/1        =====> /sub/1.html

I want the url of `http://www.example.com/sub` to be directed to sub.html instead of the directory.

** PS I dont think i can change the file structure, as it is generated by jekyll. And IIS is required. No Apache/nginx **

Would be appropriate it if anyone could help me on this!

Cheers!